# QQmlApplication not loading in release

Tags: qt, qqmlapplicationengine

I am developping a desktop application in QtQuick/C++, on windows 10. In *main()* function, I create a QQmlApplicationEngine, set some other classes as context property to it, and finally load my qml file.

Everything went well since recently, when I realize that, when I launch the application in "deployed" version, this engine has no rootObjects loaded.

However, application is starting with root object when launch in QtCreator, both in debug or release mode.

I log some infos in a separate file, and it appears that the Url loaded is valid, only there is no rootObject, and I need it. I read in doc that *load()* has to wait for objectCreated signal to be ready for remote urls, but my qml file is local, in resource file. By the way, as the *load()* stand in *main()* function, I don't see how to connect *objectCreated()* to a slot, and where to locate the slot

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
  QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
  Backend B;
  engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("backend", B);
  ...
  QUrl Url = QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/qml/main.qml"));
  engine.load(Url);
  if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
  {
    //end up here, only when launching executable stand alone!
    return -1;
  }
  return app.exec();
```

This was running fine, and I can't see which modifications in my code break the process for stand alone application.

Later in startup process, I scan the qml items of *main.qml* to retrieve some custom item's info (kind of dynamic process), and I therefore need a root object. Without object to start scan, no use to continue, and my app is shutting down.

Answer (score 0):

Oops, sorry, I did not know all the stuff about deploying qtquick application with [windeployqt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html). The only other app that I have tried was an android app, and the bundle was made directly for android target.